# Can Hex be retargeted if the initial target runs away?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, targeting

In many of our combats, some portion of our enemies run or teleport away to where we cannot engage them further. Our warlock has become concerned about effectively losing a valuable spell slot, possibly long before the combat is over.

The spell description states that you can retarget when the current target drops to 0 hit points. That is stated as a sufficient condition, not a necessary condition. It was not stated as "Only if the target drops to zero hit points...". It does not say that you can't retarget anytime you want. Usually the authors are very specific about what you can or cannot do, so for this spell it would seem that you can retarget anytime you want. My interpretation is that the authors are simply letting the players know that when the target drops to 0 health, the spell does not end.

I have tried to find an official ruling via Sage Advice and the PHB errata with no success. I was hoping that someone would have a link to an official comment on this topic, either from an original author or someone from WOTC.

Comment: heya, @spainchaud, you seem to have made two accounts, you can try merging them by following the instructions [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 23):

The description of the spell is clear on when it can be transferred:

> **If the target drops to 0 hit points** before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to curse a new
>   creature. (PHB 251, emphasis mine)

Ending the sentence in "otherwise you cannot" is unnecessary, as it is already implied. If you need to target a new creature, you can drop concentration anytime at will (PHB 203), but casting *hex* again will consume a spell slot.

Comment: The spell also doesn't specifically say you can't use it to cause the target to instantly die, or polymorph the target into a squirrel, or do any number of possible things.